# Search for unused (never passed) method parameter in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

I want to refactor a method. I want to find if the method 'myMethod' has unused parameters. for example:

```
<?php

class myClass {
    public static function myMethod($p1 = false, $p2 = false, $p3 = false) {

    }
}

myClass::myMethod(true, true);
myClass::myMethod(true);
myClass::myMethod(
  true,
  true
);
myClass::myMethod(true, true, true); // <= I want to find this..
myClass::myMethod(
  true, 
  true, 
  true); // <= ..i want also to find this..
myClass::myMethod(
  true,
  true,
  ['123', true, false, 'whatever']); // <= ..and I want also to find this..
```

Is this possible with PhpStorm usage search?

Or do I need a complex regex? How could that regex look like? The last line in my example shows the complexity, the parameter `p3` could be anything - in my example an array with further parameters in an array (`['123', true, false, 'whatever']`).

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean, "unused parameters"? wouldn't the first two, `(true)` and `(true,true)` be the ones with unused parameters?

Comment: i want to find if there was method calls with $p3 as parameter left in the code or not

Comment: PhpStorm can search for method usages .. so you can get a list of all places where this method is used and go trough each of them one by one. Other than that --- there is Structural Search .. but it can be tricky to use (do not have any real experience with this myself).

Comment: i have experience with the usage search. its good, but there is no option for specific parameter usage in my view. i think regex is the "last" option

Answer (score 0):

i think that do the job

```
myMethod\([\s\S].*,[\s\S].*,[\s\S].*\);
```

Comment: myClass::myMethod(true, ['123', true, false, 'whatever']); // <= i want not to find this..
myClass::myMethod(true, ['123', true, false, 'whatever'], true); // <= i want to find this..

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It works with "Code smell"!!

Code > Run Inspection by Name > "Parameter mismatch" :-)

[image]